# How to avois this error:only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts?

Tags: r

I have this example:

```
x=c(NA,  2,  -3,  -4,  -5,  -6,  -7,  -8,  -9, -10, -11,  -2,   2, -14, -15, -16, -17, 2, -19, -20)

g= head(x[!is.na(x)], 13)
```

I want to exclude values that were already used for g.

```
            y=x[-(head(x[!is.na(x)], 13))]

            Is there a better way to do this?
```

I got this error:

```
Error in x[-(head(x[!is.na(x)], 13))] : 
 only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

     any idea why?
```

Comment: Will `setdiff(x, g)` work?

Comment: `x[!(x %in% g)]` ?

Comment: No will not work as `2` exist in `g` bu also should not be excluded in `y` as there are two `2`.

Comment: What should be exclude is only the first 10 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%in%` to check which values are contained in `g`  and negate every index which contains a value that is contained in your definition of `g`:

```
x[!(x %in% (head(x[!is.na(x)], 13))) | (1:length(x)) > which(cumsum(!is.na(x)) == 13)]
```

Your error occurs because you are mixing positive and negative indexes in your subsetting of `x`, which is not necessary because you do not have to work with the indexes rather than create a logical vector that gives you the place for every value not contained in `g`.

EDIT: I added a second logical vector which makes sure that values after the index of the 13th non-`NA` value cannot be removed, since they can never be contained in `g` (cause `g` is a subset of the first 13 non-`NA`-values of x). There may be an easier solution but this should do it..

Comment: `NA -15 -16 -17 -19 -20`not correct as positive values `2` were removed

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the problem you are solving. If you want to delete the elements at positions 1-10 except NA, use:

> pos = c(is.na(x[1:10]), 11:length(x))
>
> y = x[-pos]

If you want to delete every element which takes the same value as the elements 2:10, then use:

> setdiff(x,g)

As per the error is concerned, I guess in your case the elements in x are a mix of positive and negative values. For example,

> letters[c(-1, -3, 5, 6, 7)]
> Error: only 0's may mix with negative subscripts

A brilliant description is given here: [https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~nolan/stat133/Fall05/notes/RSubset.html](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Enolan/stat133/Fall05/notes/RSubset.html)