# How to count NA in head of vector?

Tags: r, vector, na

```
x=c(NA, 2, -3, NA, -5, 5, -7, -8, -9, -10, NA, -2, 2, -14, -15, NA, -17, 2, NA, -20)
```

I would like to select the first 10 values that are not `NA`.
so I do:

```
head(x[!is.na(x)], 10)
```

Now I want to know how many NA were ignored:

```
sum(is.na(head(x[is.na(x)], 10)))
# [1] 5
```

which is not correct: it should be 3

Comment: What you are doing is first to filter out all non `NA` values (so your intermediate result consists only of `NA`s. Then you look at the first 10 entries (which are all the 5 `NA`s BTW) and then you count them which rightly returns `5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
sum(is.na(head(x, which(cumsum(!is.na(x)) == 10))))
```

The `cumsum` of the logical vector given by `!is.na` gives us the index of the tenth non-`NA` number, which is the input we want for the `head` function (because we want all values of until we get to the tenth non-`NA` value).

Comment: Great!. another related question you may look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55589255/how-to-avois-this-erroronly-0s-may-be-mixed-with-negative-subscripts

Answer (score 3):

We need logicla vector on the subset of actual vector and not on the NA only data

```
sum(is.na(head(x, 10)))
#[1] 3
```

---

```
head(x[is.na(x)], 10)
#[1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

gives only NAs as we are subsetting the NA elements

#### Update

Based on the logic in comments, one way is

```
i1 <- !is.na(x)
i1[i1] <- seq_along(i1[i1])
sum(is.na(head(x, which(i1 == 10))))
```

Comment: Thanks but this will consider the first 10 elements. It will be wrong in this case:x=c(NA, 2, -3, NA, -5, 5, -7, -8, -9, -10, NA, -2, 2, -14, -15, NA, -17, 2, NA, -20).   `sum(is.na(head(x, 10)))` will give `2` but the correct should be `3`.

Comment: @Tpellirn   I thtink the conditions are not clear from your question